# create json from dom document

Tags: java, xml, json

I have a org.w3c.dom.Document.
To generate the xml is no problem.
But how can I generate json out of the document ?

this is the code to get the xml string

```
        TransformerFactory transfac = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer trans = transfac.newTransformer();
        trans.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "yes");
        trans.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");

        // create string from xml tree
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        StreamResult result = new StreamResult(sw);
        DOMSource source = new DOMSource(document);
        trans.transform(source, result);
        String xmlString = sw.toString();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to solve this question.
At the end I used a different approach.
I saved the data in a Tree.

Then for Rendering the JSONView I used the JacksonJsonView Mapper.
And for Rendering the XML I used an XML Marshaller.

Comment: Have you done this way ? [https://stackoverflow.com/a/60418259/4870176 ]

Answer (score 2):

The data models for JSON and XML are different, therefore there is no canonical transformation from XML to JSON.

If you could present your data, maybe we can propose something.

Comment: actually I build the dom document out of data from a triplestore (virtuoso). I don't have any data objects as the dom is build dinamically depending on the result from a sparql query. I don't want to have static data objects.

Comment: The question is about your data format ... e.g. an example of the XML and the JSON you want to have from this could help.

Answer (score 0):

XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();

String xml= FileUtils.readFileToString(new File("test_4.xsd.xml"),Charset.defaultCharset());

JsonNode node = xmlMapper.readTree(xml.getBytes());

ObjectMapper jsonMapper = new ObjectMapper();

String json = jsonMapper.writeValueAsString(node);

System.out.println(json);

[Reference](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-convert-xml-json)