# Converting recursive XML file to JSON Object using JDOM parser in Java

Tags: java, json, xml

I am trying to convert this XML file/ or any XML file to JSON object.

```
<classes>
    <class>
        <name>MORN CS</name>
        <subjects>
            <subject>
                <title>COM101</title>
                <lessons>
                    <lesson>
                        <header>Basic</header>
                        <desc>Insert description here</desc>
                    </lesson> 
                    <lesson>
                        <header>Intros</header>
                        <desc>lorem ipsum </desc>
                    </lesson>
                </lessons>
            </subject>
        </subjects>
     </class>
</classes>
```

I have tried the code in this link but i have no idea to implement it using JDOM and its result is not the same on the xml file.
[Convert xml file to json object using dom parser in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33437908/convert-xml-file-to-json-object-using-dom-parser-in-java)
This is the result

```
{
"classes": [
    {
        "class": [
            {
                "subjects": [
                    {
                        "subject": [
                            {
                                "title": "COM101",
                                "lessons": [
                                    {
                                        "lesson": [
                                            {
                                                "header": "Intros",
                                                "desc": "lorem ipsum "
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "name": "MORN CS"
            }
        ]
    }
]}
```

Well my question is how could I convert my xml file to an JSONObject in Java?? Could someone give me idea or any help is much appreciated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33437908/convert-xml-file-to-json-object-using-dom-parser-in-java try this